# What does "A horse may stumble, though he has four feet." mean?

Tags: quotes, proverbs

English is not much of my first language, so I apologise for that first.

I've search around on Google, and notice that it's sort of a Dutch Proverb, but not much explanation about what it means.

May I please know what this quote mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means that even when something is very steady (four feet firmly planted on the ground), it can still be unstable at times. The implication is that a firm foundation isn't always enough, even though it's a very good start.